# Displaying a hierarchy(tree) using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a tree of objects in my viewModel. The objects are something like this:

```
function Node() {
    var self = this;
    self.otherNodes = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.moreNodes = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

So, the viewModel has a root node filled with Node objects in the root objects two arrays. Those Nodes may in turn have more Nodes in their arrays arbitrarily deep.

I'm having difficulty displaying this data structure in my view. A tree always suggests recursion to me but I'm not sure how to do that using knockoutjs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Template bindings can refer to themselves:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UmBku/2/

some more tips here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/-x4X2AJK0HY

Comment: Here is an additional fiddle, with a slightly more straightforward example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/yHaZT/

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the update, you should get the credit for this answer as you were the author of the original fiddle and answer I just linked too :) Also: thanks a ton for all your work to answer questions about ko in general, you've been a huge help!